# Is there a reference of the default Active Directory object attributes?

Tags: active-directory

There doesn't seem to be a single reference document where I can look up what attributes are each object class, such as group, user, person etc.

Does anyone know of one??

(would like to avoid ADSIEDIT)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MSDN Active Directory Schema document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675085(v=vs.85).aspx) should have everything that you're looking for.

Comment: Boom! Thanks. Err 2 more characters need to post this.

Answer (score 1):

While not a reference, If you just want to browse what is actually in your AD environment, use [ADExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) (a free tool from Microsoft.)